# Problems calling an as3 function from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, externalinterface

So my team's project has an swf embedded in JavaScript, we're actually using java servlet's to create the html/JavaScript. I am attempting to use as3's ExternalInterface to add a callback which would get called in the javascript but everything I have tried will not work.

Here is some of the related code:

Javascript:(remember using servlets thats why this is all inside a string)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='/oddmanor/AC_OETags.js' language='javascript'></script>
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
        var requiredMajorVersion = 10;
        var requiredMinorVersion = 1;
        var requiredRevision = 0;
    </script>
</head>
<body marginwidth='0' marginheight='0' leftmargin='0' topmargin='0'>
    <script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
    var hasReqestedVersion = DetectFlashVer(requiredMajorVersion, requiredMinorVersion, requiredRevision);
    if (hasReqestedVersion) {
        AC_FL_RunContent(
            'src', 'http://localhost:8080/download/FlashClient',
            'width', '760',
            'height', '600',
            'align', 'middle',
            'id', 'myswf',
            'quality', 'high',
            'bgcolor', '#FFFFFF',
            'name', 'myswf',
            'allowScriptAccess','always',
            'type', 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'codebase', 'http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab',
            'pluginspage', 'http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer',
            'wmode', 'opaque',
            'flashvars', 'challenge=c0oC5CjXjOpRagA0Eh0xi2uYCv-8HZfz-XpG2CCmJHZMnFQK8wYI4kultTUGYGff3N8-5lco_TrR2MfCvnUhVUyCOII6Xtem2rRIPD3SBJ18YxUSkH2GykI78Im2pfqw-UR44OqlOuZGafL3VRkn7KSiMm-AWbZt60MFHzHFaeEhIQke9aj04UkmaJL1MWoOU4CklVxoqX-ag146KilHEroL46JxcD9TLvCW9MG_Gv9fTAYOZK2_FEsHUMg0kP8WjyheWBftNxOuZoHQ9bIsB9EDe9pR4RwZryCjyL6p4T7Si0dMFfmEvml5mkhRYG74yj7pLDKTgHJeURUKOYY9RU9mFbsA82Q8-7cXeGlvQnk'
        );
    } else {
        var alternateContent = 'Alternate HTML content should be placed here.<BR>'
        + 'This content requires the Adobe Flash Player. '
        + '<a href=http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/>Get Flash</a>';
        document.write(alternateContent);
    }

    </script>
    <noscript>
    <div align="middle" id="swf">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
    <param name="src" value="http://localhost:8080/download/FlashClient">
    <param name="width" value="760">
    <param name="height" value="600">
    <param name="align" value="middle">
    <param name="id" value="myswf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">
    <param name="name" value="myswf">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="type" value="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="codebase" value="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="pluginspage" value="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="flashvars" value="challenge=c0oC5CjXjOpRagA0Eh0xi2uYCv-8HZfz-XpG2CCmJHZMnFQK8wYI4kultTUGYGff3N8-5lco_TrR2MfCvnUhVUyCOII6Xtem2rRIPD3SBJ18YxUSkH2GykI78Im2pfqw-UR44OqlOuZGafL3VRkn7KSiMm-AWbZt60MFHzHFaeEhIQke9aj04UkmaJL1MWoOU4CklVxoqX-ag146KilHEroL46JxcD9TLvCW9MG_Gv9fTAYOZK2_FEsHUMg0kP8WjyheWBftNxOuZoHQ9bIsB9EDe9pR4RwZryCjyL6p4T7Si0dMFfmEvml5mkhRYG74yj7pLDKTgHJeURUKOYY9RU9mFbsA82Q8-7cXeGlvQnk">
    <embed src="http://localhost:8080/download/FlashClient" width="760" height="600" align="middle" id="myswf" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="myswf" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="opaque" flashvars="challenge=c0oC5CjXjOpRagA0Eh0xi2uYCv-8HZfz-XpG2CCmJHZMnFQK8wYI4kultTUGYGff3N8-5lco_TrR2MfCvnUhVUyCOII6Xtem2rRIPD3SBJ18YxUSkH2GykI78Im2pfqw-UR44OqlOuZGafL3VRkn7KSiMm-AWbZt60MFHzHFaeEhIQke9aj04UkmaJL1MWoOU4CklVxoqX-ag146KilHEroL46JxcD9TLvCW9MG_Gv9fTAYOZK2_FEsHUMg0kP8WjyheWBftNxOuZoHQ9bIsB9EDe9pR4RwZryCjyL6p4T7Si0dMFfmEvml5mkhRYG74yj7pLDKTgHJeURUKOYY9RU9mFbsA82Q8-7cXeGlvQnk" />
    </object>
        This content requires the Adobe Flash Player and a browser with JavaScript enabled.
        <a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/'>Get Flash</a>
    </div>
    </noscript>
    <div>
        <a href='http://d1fjc9whyjwawe.cloudfront.net/KingX_Studios_Terms_of_Service.pdf' TARGET='_blank'>KingX Terms of Service</a> | 
        <a href='http://d1fjc9whyjwawe.cloudfront.net/Privacy_Policy_Odd_Manor.pdf' TARGET='_blank'>Privacy Policy</a> | 
        <a href='http://www.activeboard.com/forum.spark?aBID=138536&topicID=42164567&p=3' TARGET='_blank'>Report a Bug</a>
    </div>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        FB.init(
            {
                'appId': '191461020878253',
                'status': true,
                'cookie': true,
                'channelUrl': 'http://nimbus.com:8080/oddmanor/fb_channel.html'
            }
        );

        var callback = function(data) {
            var res;
            if (data['order_id']) {
                res = true;
            }
            else {
                res = false;
            }
            var me;
            if (navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft') != -1) {
                me = window['myswf'];
            }
            else {
                me = document['myswf'];
            }
            me.onPurchaseCompletion(res);
        };

        function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
           var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
           return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];  }

        function getFriendsUsingApp() 
        {
            alert("ALERRRRRT!!!");
            getFlashMovie("myswf").passFriendArrayToFlash();
            return "set2";
        }

        function makePurchase(objectInfo) {
            var obj = {
                'method': 'pay',
                'order_info': objectInfo,
                'purchase_type': 'item'
            };

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also I ripped out a bit of JavaScript code that didnt have anything to do with this problem(hopefully) so if there is a missing tag or something that's probably not my problem.

NOTE I embed this correctly and get into the swf allowing it to call javascript functions(as3 calls the getStuff fn), using the ExternalInterface, which works but JS->as3 does NOT work ='(.

Other notes, 
FlashClient *is* the name of the swf....

I cant use the movie object for anything (the return value of getFlashMovie), if I try to use no code after works...

The action script code calls the external interface addCallback function correctly(called in a try catch that's how I know)
if(External...Availible)
External...addCallback("passStuff", as3PassStuff)

The only things I can think of;
1) The embed code isnt creating the object correctly, since I cant use the movie for anything
2) my swf is being created weird and doesnt allow script access.

We are using FlashBuilder to build the swf.

Comment: Without more information on the internals of the swf, my guess is that it will be very difficult to find an answer.

Comment: Can you paste the rendered HTML instead of Java Source? also try using Firebug to see if you can run your javascript function.

Comment: Are you sure that your getFlashMovie function is returning what you expect ? If it is, then the issue would seem to be on the AS3 side. But check to ensure you are getting what you expect from that function.

Comment: @cwallenpoole Would the small amount of as3 code that goes into the external interface call/callback help? You could probably find it in most of the tutorials on the subject. I will post it though unless you're talking about other 'swf' settings..?

I will attempt to post the rendered HTML tomorrow. Along with as3 code if it seems to apply.

@Prototypical - Do you know what the problem may be if that function is not returning a value(or the right one)??? I am new to both HTML and JavaScript.

Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: The html which is created from the java stuff is posted now instead of what I had previously.

Comment: Alright this is the OP again, we have deduced the problem is coming from where the swf is located. If we place the swf in the same location as the constructed HTML page. Meaning we change "http://localhost:8080/download/FlashClient" to "/FlashClient" via moving the actual swf and it works. 
Does anyone have any idea about how to allow access to other folders or paths for our swf movie to have calling privileges from???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.security.allowDomain("*");
```

in my swf and we're good.